# highchart update plotline's label when plotline have move animation

Tags: highcharts

I'm working on similar problem mentioned in the post

[highchart plotline can have move animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044463/highchart-plotline-can-have-move-animation)

I need to enhance it by adding label to plotline. When ever plotline location changes, its label should also change and its location as well, showing the current Y axis value.

Comment: Add a label to the plot line - see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands.label) Then you you need to animate this label the same way as in the fiddle in the link, like yAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0].label.animate({translateY: newValue}) http://jsfiddle.net/8qd9ezhv/

Comment: Thank you. That solution worked.

Comment: I need to give background color to label for which i'm using style. Style is not getting applied, until i use 'useHTML' as true. Once 'useHTML' is true, label does not move with plotline. Is there anyway to make it work.

Comment: Html elements are handled differently than svg elements - you need to animate html on your own with js or css3. You can also try to override renderLabel method so it will support label - it will work for a horizontal plot line (it wont work for rotated text/label)  http://jsfiddle.net/8qd9ezhv/1/

Comment: I tried the suggestion u gave. This way i'm able to move label after using renderLabel. Could you please let me know, if i can update the label value dynamically. i tried different ways , its not working.    http://jsfiddle.net/anuPai/hohtdgbL/2/